# ng-animate for page transitions has weird behaviour with responsive media queries

Tags: angularjs, media-queries, css-transitions, ng-animate

My angular app uses ng-animate to animate page transitions. However I'd like to only have this behaviour on desktop and not on mobile. I am dynamically setting CSS transitions based on the screen size like so:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .page.ng-enter {
      transition: all 0.3s linear;
      opacity: 0;
  }

  .page.ng-enter-active {
      opacity: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

This works fine, on small screen sizes no animation is shown and on bigger screens it is. However if you resize the screen to a small size, navigate and resize it bigger again no animation is ever shown again (until a refresh).

EDIT: here is a live link of the app:

http://beta.wizb.it/